# How to get controller base path from request in spring

Tags: spring, request

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(/menu)
@PreAuthorize("@customPermissionEvaluator.hasAuthority()")
public class MenuController {
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity getAllMenus() {

}
```

This is the controller. I want to get **/menu** only from request in the custom **preauthorized method**. I dont want to send as hardcoded.

This is the method:

```
@Service
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator {

String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
//this returns /menu/all

}
```

This return  **/menu/all**

But I want to get 
**/menu**

Also `request.getServletPath()` returns same.

Do  I need string operations? Like `request.getRequestURI().substring(0,  requestURI.lastIndexOf('/'))`

Comment: What is the purpose actually? SInce its coming inside `getAllMenus` method, you know the requested URL is `/menu/all` no?

Comment: @vipincp yes i know. I will give authority to all /menu requests if user has access to /menu menu.

Comment: Why do you not implement PermissionEvaluator interface in CustomPermissionEvaluator  ?

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek i dont want to send parameters. `hasPermission` needs two parameters